# javascript for auto image slider with html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code is my html page for image slider but it  will not continue after sliding last image.

```
<style type="text/css">
#slideshow {
position:relative;
height:300px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
z-index:9;
}
</style>'


<script>
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('div#slideshow IMG.active');
    var $next = $active.next();    

    $next.addClass('active');

}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
</script>'

<body>
<div id="slideshow" style="height:300px; width:100%">
<img src="${context:layout/images/images.jpeg}" title="Funky roots"     style="position:absolute; height:300px; width:100%;" class="active"/>
<img src="${context:layout/images/police.jpg}" title="The long and  winding road" style="position:absolute; height:300px; width:100%;"/>
<img src="${context:layout/images/viper_1.jpg}" title="Happy trees"   style="position:absolute; height:300px; width:100%;"/>
</div>
</body>
```

From this code, how can I get auto sliding and continue to next slide after a last image?

Comment: I have delete that last.active class but still now its not working after a last image.Its working like from first image last image by automatic but after a last it will stop.

Comment: Corrected typos, removed "thanks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont add the `last-active` class to the last element. So every element has the `active` class and every element has `z-index: 10`

After some work on the code got this new JS for you:

```
function slideSwitch() {
  var $active = $('div#slideshow IMG.active');
  var $next = $active.next();    
  $active.addClass('last-active');
  $active.removeClass('active');
  if($next.length == 0) {
    $next = $('div#slideshow IMG').first(); //at the end we need to select the first element, because there is no next()
  }
  $next.removeClass('last-active');
  $next.addClass('active');
}
```

EDIT:

TO answer your comment:

After the first round through your slider the classes look like this:

```
<img ... class="last-active"/>
<img ... class="last-active"/>
<img ... class="active"/>
```

When we enter the code `$active` contains the last `div` and `$next` is empty, because there is no next element.

At this point we have to tell the code, that the next element will be the first one. The `$next = $('div#slideshow IMG').first();` just select the first div where we want to start over.

Comment: Its working fine, but i have one doubt in that if condition.
if($next.length == 0) {
    $next = $('div#slideshow IMG').first();
}
why you have used that $next=$('div#slideshow IMG').first();

Comment: Ya i got it.And one more question about this image slider is,
    suppose if we want to make a next image movement like a animation which code i want to add.